# When does Cloudformation Drift check occur?

Tags: aws-cloudformation

Aside from the Check Drift function in the web console, are there other triggers for the check?

Does cloudformation automatically checks for drift prior to a stack update?

Lets say I have a cf stack that created an s3 bucket. Then I manually altered some property of the s3 bucket from the web console. Then I run a stack update using the exact cf template I used to create the stack.

Will the stack update action trigger a drift check and detect that it has to revert the changed properties? Or since the template is still exactly the same as before, it won't do anything. Despite the s3 bucket already in a drifted state?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drift detection will never run automatically. You always trigger it yourself, either in the console or in the CLI or over the API.

In your scenario, the stack update will revert the manual change, presuming that the property was within the scope of the original template.

Comment: If the drift check does not occur, how does it know that it needs to revert the manual change?

Comment: It will still check if the properties are set correctly, but not in the same way as the explicit drift detection feature does. E.g. it will not pause and notify you about it, it will just overwrite any manual changes.